# jquery hide and show function not working

Tags: jquery

I have a job site and am trying to show element of class "start_hidden) every time a link is clicked. (Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/t29w5cb3/ of a larger example but I included all the necessary code below )

jquery:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".job_link").click(function(){
                $("start_hidden").show();
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

html:

```
     <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="job_results_nested_grid">
                        <div class="job">
                            <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">Delivery  - Pizza Hut</a></h2>
                            <p class="job_p">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur corporis dolor eius facere laboriosam libero minima necessitatibus nobis nulla, officiis optio quis tempore vel. Exercitationem harum ipsum perspiciatis unde voluptate!</p>
                            <p class="start_hidden">salary: 12</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="job">
                            <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">Delivery  - Pizza Hut</a></h2>
                            <p class="job_p">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur corporis dolor eius facere laboriosam libero minima necessitatibus nobis nulla, officiis optio quis tempore vel. Exercitationem harum ipsum perspiciatis unde voluptate!</p>
                        </div>
               </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.start_hidden{
display: none;
}

</style>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I feel like it may have to do with my css but I am new to jquery so I am not sure

Comment: Do you include jquery in your app?

Comment: oh yes im sorry I should have included that, I edited the question but the source code did originally include the jquery link

Comment: Include jquery into your app: https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).parents('.job')` since both elements are children of `<div class="job">` and you only want to show the one next to the one you clicked on

```
$(".job_link").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.job').find(".start_hidden").show();
});
```

Comment: The parent of the `.job-link` is an `<h2>`. You probably want to do `$(this).closest('.job').find( ... )` instead.

Comment: @TylerRoper you are right, sir. Changed it to `parents('.job')` which suppose to work the same way

Comment: `.parents()` will work in this scenario, the only difference to note is that `parents()` will select all parent elements that satisfy the selector, so if there were nested `.job` elements (unlikely), you could run into a snag. `closest()` is usually a bit safer when you know you're only going to want *one* element :) In any case, good answer. +1

Comment: great solution, how to show one at a time was going to be my next question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("start_hidden").show();
```

change to

```
$(".start_hidden").show();
```

Comment: such a simple change that I would have literally never caught, thank you!

Comment: This will `show` all elements with `start_hidden` class if there will be multiple on the page

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class

```
 $(".start_hidden").show();
```